# Vue js invalid router after login

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm totally new to `vue` and I've built small vue app in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-fjd4i

And I have problems with routing, so, how to reproduce it:

1. click `Login` and provide any credentials
2. So now you are on `Board page`
3. Click `Statistics` page
4. And I get `Signup` page instead of `Statistics`, why? I don't understand

I'm using `EventBus` to refresh navbar after login `event-bus.js`:

```
// EventBus.js
import Vue from "vue";
export default new Vue();
```

When I'm logged (on `Board` page) and I click on `Statistics` I can see wrong route in `router/index.js` `beforeEach` func:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log("///////");
  console.log(from);
  console.log(to);
  console.log(next);
  console.log("///////");
```

So i'm getting `Signup` route in `to` variable instead of `Statistics`. Can please anybody help?

Comment: It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `<a>` tags, don't know why, but kill vue routing, so I changed this:

```
<router-link v-if="is_logged" tag="li" :to="{ name: 'Statistics' }">
  <a>Statistics</a>
</router-link>
```

to this:

```
<li v-if="is_logged"><router-link tag="a" :to="{ name: 'Statistics' }">
  Statistics
</router-link></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen If your route definition uses async loading `import(...)`, and you named the chunks the same.  Check the comment that declares the names in your routes.

Also, make sure your `Statistics` route really does return the correct component. Did you cut-and-paste?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but I cant understand what do you mean. Caches? Were are they, in what file?
Regarding `Statistics` component should I return `name` parametr in `export default`?

Comment: There are comments used to define the chunk filename for lazy routes.  If multiple routes use the same chunk name, the server will serve the wrong component.